# how to load a template in the same file using ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

I've seen an example this somewhere but now I can't find it in the docs or google

basically, I wish to define a template:

`<script type="text/ng-template" id="loginform">....</script>`

and then use it on the same page:

`<div ng-include="'views/page/user.html#loginform'">`

I've tried a couple of alternatives but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to omit the path from the src attribute e.g:

```
<div ng-include src="'loginform'"></div>
```

Comment: hahaha... that was the one that I missed btw.. can the loginform template be accessed if it was in another file?

Comment: good question. Doesn't look like you can do it out of the box w/ angular. Seems possible though https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/3354046